# Directional derivatives and unit vector

Tags: derivatives, vectors

I have an exercise in my textbook saying the following:

> Let $f : R^2 → R$ be defined by $z(x, y) = x^3 − 2x^2y + xy^2 + 1$. Find the directional derivative at $(1, 2)$ along the direction towards $(4, 6)$.

While I understand the process and the evaluation process, I don't understand my teachers approach to finding the unit vector.

According to the solution it is this:

> We have $x = (1, 2), y = (3, 4)$ because the direction is given by the difference of the two points.

Yet, using the normal approach, I would get

$u=\frac{(4,6)}{\sqrt{4^2+6^2}} = (\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}},\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}})$

Meaning his solution is $5$, while mine is $\frac{4\sqrt{13}}{13}$

Who is right and if he is, why is my approach wrong and how does his' work?

Comment: I think you might be confusing $x$ and $y$. The direction vector is given by $\langle 6-2, 4-1\rangle=\langle 4,3\rangle.$ That is, the $x$ component is $4$ and the $y$ component is $3$.

Comment: Wait I am not really following. Are you talking about the first or second (yellow) blockquote? Those are given by the teacher.

Comment: You have to subtract $(4,6)$ by $(1,2)$ to find the direction.

Comment: I was using the explanation on this site: https://mathinsight.org/directional_derivative_gradient_examples to find the unit vector. So is it wrong?

Comment: The difference is that the website already gives you the direction but your teacher doesn’t. $(4,6)$ is not the direction. It’s a point! You have to find the vector at $(1.2)$ that gives you the direction towards $(4.6)$

Comment: This is found by subtracting the two coordinates since that gives you the directional vector.

Comment: Ohhh thanks. I mean he could be clearer. The only indication this was a point was using (,) instead of <,>. A convention which is often ignored...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are wrong. $(4,6)$ is not the direction, it’s a point and you have to find the direction by subtracting your two points.

We want to find the directional derivative in the direction $<3,4>$ since it’s a direction you have to take to reach that point. (This was found by subtracting our two points to find the vector that points in the correct direction).

The unit vector is $<3/5,4/5>$. The gradient is $(f_x,f_y)$ and is equal to $(-1,2)$ at your point.

Take the dot product of your gradient vector (normal to your level curve) with the unit normal vector to find the answer.

Comment: I was using the explanation on this site: mathinsight.org/directional_derivative_gradient_examples to find the unit vector. So is it wrong?

Comment: The problem is that that website gives you the direction vector but your teachers wants you to find the directional vector by subtracting your two points and finding the correct directional vector.

Comment: Yeah got it now! Thank you!

Comment: Hey sorry one more question. There are now 2 ways to calculate it. According to my professor it is: $(-1,2) * (3,4) = 5$. Doing the same with $3/5,4/5$ yields $1$. Which one is it?

Comment: You need the unit vector so the second one correct. The length of your direction should not have an impact on the rate of change.

Answer (score 0):

This confused me a lot too. I think the answer is in the semantics. If we are finding the directional derivative in the direction "towards a point (x, y, z)", we have to subtract. But if we are finding it without reference toward the points, then just take a unit vector without substracting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).